# Angular validation messages don't work with ng-show and two inputs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have implemented a form with a mode. Form can have 'Create' or 'Edit' mode. Depending on the mode it shows some div in one place of the layout or another. Div content is the same and it's input and some validation messages for it.

Here's simplified example.

**View:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <form name="editForm">
     <div ng-show='mode == "Edit"'>
       <div class="form-group" ng-class="{true:'has-error',false:''}[editForm.FirstName.$valid === false && editForm.FirstName.$dirty]">
          <input type="text" ng-model="foo" ng-maxlength="5" name="foo" required />
          <div class="help-block" ng-messages="editForm.foo.$error" ng-if="editForm.foo.$dirty">
            <p ng-message="required">Required</p>
            <p ng-message="maxlength">Too long</p>
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div ng-show='mode == "Create"'>
       <div class="form-group" ng-class="{true:'has-error',false:''}[edit.foo.$valid === false && edit.foo.$dirty]">
          <input type="text" ng-model="foo" ng-maxlength="5" name="foo" required />
          <div class="help-block" ng-messages="editForm.foo.$error" ng-if="editForm.foo.$dirty">
            <p ng-message="required">Required</p>
            <p ng-message="maxlength">Too long</p>
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </form>
      <div>
      Mode: {{mode}} <br>
      Value: {{foo}} <br>
      Is form valid: {{editForm.foo.$valid}} <br>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngMessages']);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.mode = 'Edit';
});
```

**[Here's JSFiddle with working example](http://jsfiddle.net/9ctgn364/7/).**

The problem is - validation messages work properly only when the last input is shown. In Edit mode - even if it's the same - messages don't show correctly.

Comment: I didn't understand, what's the problem... what your problem?

Comment: In Edit mode validation messages don't show. See demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/9ctgn364/7/ - switch between modes and try to input string longer than 5 in both modes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `ng-show` use `ng-if` directive.

`ng-show` causes browser to render both `div` elements, with `ng-hide` class on the element where `ng-show` expression is evaluated as `false`.

`ng-if` on the other hand causes `div` element to be not rendered if `ng-if` expression is `false`.